# changing my textfield to upper/lower case is not working as intended

Tags: javafx

After creating my GUI my next step was to have the buttons be able to change the textfield to their respective case when pressed. However none of the ways I have tried seem to demonstrate that.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpperLowerClass extends Application  {

    private Button upperButton;
    private Button lowerButton;
    private String userText;
    private TextField userInput;
    private Stage window;



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);   

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Uppercase to Lowercase");


        //GRID
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);


        //UPPERCASE BUTTON
        upperButton = new Button("Uppercase");
        upperButton.setOnAction(this::changeTextButton);
        GridPane.setConstraints(upperButton, 0, 0);

        //LOWERCASE BUTTON
        lowerButton = new Button("Lowercase");
        lowerButton.setOnAction(this::changeTextButton);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lowerButton, 0, 1);

        //TEXTFIELD
        TextField userInput = new TextField();
        userInput.getText();
        userInput.setText(String.valueOf(userText));
        GridPane.setConstraints(userInput, 0, 2);


        grid.getChildren().addAll(upperButton, lowerButton, userInput);


        //SCENE
        Scene myScene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(myScene);
        window.show();

        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }
    //EVENT
    public void changeTextButton(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() ==upperButton) {
            userText = userText.toUpperCase();
        }
        if  (event.getSource() ==lowerButton) {
            userInput.setText(String.valueOf(userText.toLowerCase()));
        }



    }



}
```

There must be a problem with how I am retrieving the text or is it entirely because of the manipulation I am trying to do in the If statements? Each button is the two versions I have tried which leads me to think that I am retrieving the text wrong or manipulating wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Get rid of `userText` and just use the `TextField`. `userInput.setText(userInput.getText().toUpperCase());`.   `TextField userInput = new TextField();` <- get rid of this. It should be `userInput = new TextField();`

Answer (score 0):

Is the String userText needed elsewhere? Getting and setting the text of userInput directly through getText() and setText() would be better imo. Additionally, there is no need to create a local variable for userInput when you have it as a global variable already.

This is your code tested working: (I removed the changeTextButton method and just made the changes from the buttons directly, but this could be split out easily enough.)

public class UpperLowerClass extends Application {

```
private Button upperButton;
private Button lowerButton;
private TextField userInput;
private Stage window;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

        window = primaryStage;

        //GRID
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);


        //UPPERCASE BUTTON
        upperButton = new Button("Uppercase");
        upperButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(userInput.getText()!=null) {
                userInput.setText(userInput.getText().toUpperCase());
            }
        });
       // upperButton.setOnAction(this::changeTextButton);
        GridPane.setConstraints(upperButton, 0, 0);

        //LOWERCASE BUTTON
        lowerButton = new Button("Lowercase");
        //lowerButton.setOnAction(this::changeTextButton);
        lowerButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(userInput.getText()!=null) {
                userInput.setText(userInput.getText().toLowerCase());
            }
        });
        GridPane.setConstraints(lowerButton, 0, 1);

        //TEXTFIELD
        userInput = new TextField(); //don't need to create new Textfield here
        GridPane.setConstraints(userInput, 0, 2);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(upperButton, lowerButton, userInput);

        //SCENE
        Scene myScene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(myScene);
        window.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}